# How do I set up Searx on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 20.04, browser

I am a total noob, please help.

I appear to have got the dependencies from step 1, here:

https://searx.github.io/searx/admin/installation-searx.html#installation-basic

The source code file is here:

https://github.com/searx/searx/releases/tag/v0.17.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to compile it.

Simply use [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/searx) from repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install searx
```

Then run it with `searx-run`.

Comment: Installation worked but the search engine and that last command don't.